# read but for Text in haskell?

Tags: haskell

is there a function like "read" but for Text instead of String?

```
read :: Read a => Text -> a
```

i have already looked up in the documentation and it is not there

Answer (score 6):

We can use [Hoogle](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=Read%20a%20%3D%3E%20Text%20%2D%3E%20a&scope=set%3Astackage) to check for that exact type signature.

It's not in `base`. There's a version of `read` like the one you want provided by the `basic-prelude` alternative prelude. But, if you understandably aren't ready to take the leap on alternative preludes, the definition is pretty simple.

```
import qualified Data.Text as Text

tread :: Read a => Text.Text -> a
tread = read . Text.unpack
```